# Как грамотно анализировать этот чёртов массив?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Прошу, не ругайте сильно за столь "профанские" вопросы, я только начинаю изучать PHP.

Итак, есть два массива.
С ними требуются некоторые взаимодействия, я понимаю принцип, но операторов в языке так много, что я не могу выбрать нужный.

Примерные массивы:

```
$prog=array('program analiz
begin
int i, n ; {Описание переменных}
float sum ; {Описание переменных}
readln n ; {Указание количества итераций}
sum:= 0.31e-1 ;
i:=1 ;
while (i<=n)
begin
sum:=sum+(1/i);
i:=i+1;
end
writeln sum; {Вывод результата}
end.');

$oper='program,var,begin,end,ass,if,then,else,for,to,do,while,read,write,true,false';
```

1. Каким образом из $prog удалить "комментарии" (фигурные скобки с содержимым)? Предполагаю, что лучше использовать регулярку, но мои варианты не действуют.
2. Из $prog выбрать совпадающие элементы строки $oper и поместить их в новый массив (допустим, $operators) без привязки к регистру и исключая повторения.
   Я думаю, что тут применим array_filter, но опять ничего не вышло.
3. Как выгрузить в ещё один массив ($ost) оставшиеся слова без цифр и знаков?
4. И как выгрузить в новый массив ($cif) числа через запятую? Тоже пытался через регулярки..

Если Вы не против, то как можно подробнее, чтобы не только смог использовать, но и понять хочется.

Comment: Вопрос: в каждом элементе массива должен находиться текст отдельной программы или отдельная строка одной программы?

Comment: Как я понимаю, лучше всего, перевести $prog в строку. Делал через implode '$prog =  = implode(",", $prog);', но не срабатывает.

Comment: Вот как выглядят массивы в пхп - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

а $prog — это массив с одним элементом и весь текст в нём это одна строка. var_dump($prog); - всё это покажет наглядно.

Answer (score 4):

Начнем с того, что **массивов в этом задании нет.** Ни одного.
И к РНР задача отношения не имеет.

А лексические анализаторы пишутся *совсем* не так, как изложено в вопросе. Если эту задачу *действительно* нужно решать, то рекомендую начать вот с [этой статьи](http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/How_To_Write_A_Simple_Lexical_Analyzer_or_Parser).

Но я бы порекомендовал отложить эту задачу на время, и заняться изучением РНР. Чтобы хотя бы не путать строки с массивами и хотя бы приблизительно представлять, как за неё браться.

Comment: Согласен, просто $prog берётся через форму методом POST.
Найти такой метод, чтобы автоматически из <textarea> значение присваивалось строкой я не смог.
Перевести в строку у меня не получилось через implode.

За ссылку спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Значение textarea это и есть строка. Если значение взято с POST зачем оно обвернуто в массив, в вашем случае лучше сделать через regexp функция preg_replace
[Почитайте здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)